# How to have users submit photos onto webpage

Tags: debugging, pythonanywhere

I need help having user submit photos onto webpage and having those photos be 1)saved into a folder I created 2)show on the webpage. Ignore the off spacing for html code it is correct on my document.

In my error log it says:

> 2019-11-30 18:52:15,229:   File "/home/HassanSherien/.virtualenvs/flask-tutorial/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2097, in make_response
>   2019-11-30 18:52:15,229:     "The view function did not return a valid response. The"

Python Code:

```py
def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
           filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS
#@app.route('/upload', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/upload', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # check if the post request has the file part
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            flash('No file part')
            return redirect(request.url)
        file = request.files['file']
        # if user does not select file, browser also
        # submit a empty part without filename
        if file.filename == '':
            flash('No selected file')
            return redirect(request.url)
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            flash(file)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            return redirect(url_for('uploaded_file',filename=filename))

    elif request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("overview_main_page.html", comments=Comment.query.all())
    return

@app.route('/uploads/<filename>', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def uploaded_file(filename):
    return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],
                               filename)
```

Html Code:

```
  <div class="w3-panel">
    <div class="w3-row-padding" style="margin:0 -16px">
      <div class="w3-third">
       <form action="{{ url_for('upload_file') }}" method="post">
       <!-- <form action="{{ url_for('upload_file') }}" method='POST'> -->
       <input type="file" name="file" value="fileupload" id="file_upload">
       <input type='submit' />
```

Comment: This function   ```  def upload_file():``` has no return. you have added response for all the if conditions what if they are not satisfied so you have to return outside the if condition also.

Comment: Could you clarify what you meant by "return outside the if condition" I thought I did that that return that is right below it?@Pygirl

Comment: Upload_file() I meant. Can you show the whole traceback.

Comment: https://www.pythonanywhere.com/user/HassanSherien/files/var/log/hassansherien.pythonanywhere.com.error.log @Pygirl I am not sure if this will open up for you

Comment: It's asking for credential

Comment: Could we change this to a private discussion and I could upload the photos there? Or would you like me to screenshot it and edit the post above? @Pygirl

Comment: upload screenshot

Comment: Why your if condition is inside another if    `if file and allowed_file(file.filename):`

Comment: It was an indentation issue! I edited it above. As of right now I get no debugging error but my follow up question would be, where are these photos being saved? I created a path for them and I thought they would show up in my folder on pythonanywhere but they do not. @Pygirl

Comment: app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] check it's path and create folder if not exist.

Comment: This is what the path is ``UPLOAD_FOLDER = '/home/HassanSherien/mysite/Shape_Image/'`` and the folders does exist yet nothing shows up sadly @Pygirl

Comment: Check your if else condition once again. I have used the same code for my project too and it works.

Comment: I find most of your if else and sentence misplaced in the code.

Comment: Your seems too buggy for me.

Comment: Can you elaborate! In term of the format I used the flask documentation to write most of it. If you do work on codementor I would not mind entering a session for I am a beginner and am not sure how to go about this issue @Pygirl

Comment: There are lot of indentations bug in your code. Are sure your original code look like this?

Comment: I have edited above what it looks like in my document. @Pygirl